# Left and right derivative

Tags: limits, derivatives

Find the left and right derivative of $f(x) = (2+|x|)e^x$ in x = 0.

This is how I started (with the derivative from the right):

$$\lim _{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h} =$$

$$\lim _{h\to 0^+}\frac{(2+|0+h|)e^{0+h} - (2+|0|)e^{0}}{h} = \lim _{h\to 0^+}\frac{(2+h)e^h - 2}{h}$$

This is as far as I have gotten. Am I approaching it the right way? How do I continue from here? I can't see how to get rid of $h$ in the denominator.

Comment: $e^h = 1 + h + O(h^2)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the standard limit $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h-1}{h}=1$?

Answer (score 1):

$|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. If you want the equation of the derivative for your function $g(x)$ I suggest you consider $x>0$ and $x<0$ separately. There's a jump discontinuity at 0 of course. Also keep in mind $\lim f(x) g(x) = \lim f(x) \lim g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$...=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{(2+h)e^h-(2+0)e^0}{h}=\frac{d}{dx}(2+x)e^x\Big|_{x=0}=...$$

Comment: I think this takes care only of the right side, One should also consider $h \to 0^{-}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
(2+x)e^x & x\geq 0 & \\ 
(2-x)e^x & x< 0 & 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Now $f'(x)|_{0_{+}}$ and $f'(x)|_{0_{-}}$ are equal to...